# Lexical error in R elastic package when creating mapping

Tags: json, r, elasticsearch

I'm having trouble executing some functions of the R package [elastic](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elastic/index.html) (elastic_0.7.8). Specifically, I'm trying to use the `mapping_create` function to create a mapping from a JSON string.

No matter which JSON format I'm using, I'm always getting the same error. For instance, executing one example from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elastic/elastic.pdf) (page 38):

```
library(elastic)
connect(es_host = "host_url", es_port = 9210, es_path = "/")

body <- '{
      "citation": {
      "properties": {
      "journal": { "type": "string" },
      "year": { "type": "long" }
    }
  }
}'

> mapping_create(index = "plos", type = "citation", body=body)
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       No handler found for uri [///pl
                     (right here) ------^
```

Other package functions work fine, for instance, I can execute `mapping_get('_all')` and retrieve all the indexes, or use `mapping_get(index = "createdIndex")` and retrieve an already created index. Did anybody have a similar issue?

EDITED.

Elasticsearch version 5.2.2
R version 3.3.2

```
> mapping_get(index = "plos", type = "citation", config=httr::verbose())
-> GET //plos/_mapping/citation HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.29.0 r-curl/2.2 httr/1.2.1
-> Host: server-url:9200
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<- content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<- content-encoding: gzip
<- transfer-encoding: chunked
<- 
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       No handler found for uri [//tpm
                     (right here) ------^
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED 2:

After installing a new version from github `elastic_0.7.8.9614`, another error is shown:

```
> mapping_create(index = "plos", type = "citation", body=body)
Error: 404 - no such index
```

`sessionInfo()` result:

```
other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.0  R.utils_2.5.0      R.oo_1.21.0        R.methodsS3_1.7.1  elastic_0.7.8.9614

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1   R6_2.2.0     tools_3.3.2  curl_2.6     jsonlite_1.5
```

EDITED 3

```
> config=httr::verbose()
> print(config)
<request>
Options:
* debugfunction: function (type, msg) 
{
    switch(type + 1, text = if (info) prefix_message("*  ", msg), headerIn = prefix_message("<- ", msg), headerOut = prefix_message("-> ", msg), dataIn = if (data_in) prefix_message("<<  ", msg, TRUE), dataOut = if (data_out) prefix_message(">> ", msg, TRUE), sslDataIn = if (data_in && ssl) prefix_message("*< ", msg, TRUE), sslDataOut = if (data_out && ssl) prefix_message("*> ", msg, TRUE))
}
* verbose: TRUE
```

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here - What R version and `elasticsearch` version are you using?  Looks like a problem in parsing JSON. and what does `mapping_get(index = "plos", type = "citation", config=httr::verbose())` give you (redacting sensitive urls/ports/whatever)

Comment: Have you tried leaving `es_path`  as NULL (same as `""`) - i think that's not generally needed unless you have some characters after the base URL

Comment: @sckott with `es_path=""` I get `Error: 404 - no such index`. I was thinking that maybe it was something related to the API changes in Elasticsearch 5.x, but reading the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking_50_rest_api_changes.html) the only change I see is that unquoted JSONs are now forbidden.

Comment: Are you giving `es_host` with a trailing slash or without? and does that make a difference? i imagine it does - if so, we can improve normalizing urls

Comment: @sckott If I use trailing slash, I get message in the question (`Error: lexical error: invalid...`). If I don't use trailing slash (`es_host = ""`), I just get the message `Error: 404 - no such index`.

Comment: looking into it here https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/181

Comment: made a change. try reinstalling `devtools::install_github("ropensci/elastic")` and try again, should be fixed

Comment: @sckott Thank you very much for the help. Unfortunatelly, after reinstalling the package (`elastic_0.7.8.9614`) and re-starting a clean R session, the error `Error: 404 - no such index` is shown. This error appears whith both `es_path = "/"` and `es_path = ""` in the `connect` statement. Other functions such as `docs_bulk` work fine. I have updated the question with the `sessionInfo()`. Maybe should I update other packages such as `httr`?

Comment: no, updating other pkgs shouldn't make a difference. not sure why you're still getting that problem. what does verbose curl output `config=httr::verbose() ` give you now

Comment: @sckott I have updated the question.

Comment: sorry, i meant using verbose in the `elastic` function call that is giving you the error

Comment: @sckott Sorry, I've tried setting the `verbose = TRUE` option in the `mapping_create` call but it shows the same output.